# C# abrir otras aplicaciones

Tags: c#

¿Como podría llamar aplicaciones externas a la mía sin tener que usar una ruta?
¿Hay alguna otra forma?

Answer (score 2):

Para lanzas una aplicacion simplemente indicando el nombre del ejecutable debes indicarle al sistema operativo alguna carpeta predefinidas donde buscar esa aplicacion.

Estas carpetas las defines en el `Environment Variable` en este caso de Windows

[Launching external programs in C# without knowing the exact path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199335/launching-external-programs-in-c-sharp-without-knowing-the-exact-path)

Si indicas alli la carpeta donde pondrias el ejecutable que quieres lanzar entonces desde codigo solo indicar el nombre, sin la ruta

Entiendo que vas a usaer el metodo `Process.Start("nombreapp.exe")` para lanzar la aplicaicon

Answer (score 0):

Una forma puede ser:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es únicamnete abrir la otra aplicación sin interactuar, con la siguiente línea basta:

```
Process.Start("snippingtool.exe");
```

Sólo tienes que especificar entre paréntesis el nombre del ejecutable de la aplicación.